# STM32 Programming Using Infrared

Tags: circuit-design, pcb-design, programming, infrared

I'm trying to program STM32 using [IR Emitter](https://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/DS-50-92-0026/LTE-4206(E).pdf) and [PT](https://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/DS-50-92-0073/R4206E.pdf).

While trying this, there is interaction between the programmer and the PCB, but since the signals rise late, I get an error before I can send the program. This **same circuit worked** when I tried it on **another PCB**, but it doesn't work on the new PCB I designed.

What could be the reason for the late rise in the signal? What changes should I make in the circuit? Should I have designed the circuit close to the IC?

[image][image]

Comment: What transistor Q2 transistor is? Why it is in the circuit to begin with, instead of just PT1?

Comment: If the same circuit used to work on a different PCB, and now the same circuit doesn't work on your new PCB, why wouldn't you thing the problem is with the PCB?

Comment: @Justme, I have not designed a similar circuit before. I tried one of the sample circuits and since it worked, I did not want to make any changes to the circuit. I tried remove Q2 from the circuit before and got the same result. (Q2: MMBT3904-TP)

Comment: @MOSFET, You're right. I have a problem with the PCB. But I can't quite understand what the problem is. Because this is the 2nd version of the PCB and the problem remains the same.

Comment: @harmonica Can you run a dual trace at the same time: one probe on emitter of PT1 and one probe on Collector of Q2? This will break the problem in half. This problem certainly looks like capacitance related or resistors to high in value based on the response.

Comment: And (optionally) one probe on the IR LED just for fun.

Comment: @MOSFET, The problem is caused by the P-MOS(DMP31D7L) I use for switching. The IR_VCC voltage drops very similar to the graph above. S=3V6, D=IR_VCC, G=MCU_Enable. I removed the P-MOS from the circuit and shorted the S and D pads. The circuit worked smoothly. I have used the same switching circuit many times and have never encountered such a voltage drop.

Comment: You should revise your schematic cause none of what you said is presented here. You need to put the MOSFET circuitry.

Comment: @MOSFET, I connected the Drain and Source pins incorrectly... I connected S instead of D and D instead of S :')